# What is the shape of the universe?

Tags: cosmology, spacetime, universe, topology

If it's flat then how a volume can be flat?
And I've read that it's actually not flat .....it's a "Poincaré dodecahedral space".
Any suggestions for books posts or articles are highly appreciated.

Comment: “Flat” doesn’t mean flat like a piece of paper. It means “no spatial curvature”. There is no compelling evidence to support the Poincaré dodecahedral space idea.

Comment: “As of 2016, the publication of data analysis from the Planck spacecraft suggests that there is no observable non-trivial topology to the universe.” (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homology_sphere) What you read is out-of-date.